# Passing dynamic number of HTML elements to Apex class

Tags: apex, html

I have a non-stable number of HTML elements "*they are generated at runtime*" that **I want to pass to APEX controller and do some processing on them.**

Here is an example of HTML elements
[image]

One more thing, after passing them, is there a way to read them as key-value ?

Answer (score 2):

This page:

```
<apex:page controller="SubmitController">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:form>
        <input type="text" name="dynamic_1"/>
        <input type="text" name="dynamic_2"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and controller:

```
public with sharing class SubmitController {
    public PageReference submit() {
        Map<String, String> m = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        for (String key : m.keySet()) {
            if (key.startsWith('dynamic_')) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
                        ApexPages.Severity.INFO,
                        'key=' + key + ' value=' + m.get(key)
                        ));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

illustrate that you can get the values of named form fields from the `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()` collection. So use a naming convention for the name attributes of your "generated at runtime" fields and pull values that match that convention out of the collection and process them as you require.